# Plotting lat long on World Map

Tags: php, mysql

I have lat long coordinates of various merchant ships of the world, say 50000. And I have around 100 instances of coordinates (lat long) of each of these ships at various timestamps.

I have them on my sql db and I wish to plot the tracks of each ship on World Map, not necessarily Google Map.

Please guide how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be online you could use javascript mapping libraries such as [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) or [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/). You could then load all the data from your database and plot the coordinates on the map.

Another approach which requires less programming would be to import the coordinates into GIS software, like e.g. QGIS. There's also a nice plugin for QGIS called [qgis2web](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2web/) (see also this blog post: [Quick webmaps with qgis2web](http://anitagraser.com/2015/10/01/quick-webmaps-with-qgis2web/)) which creates a webmap from your data.